# perl script does not print after first run of do-while statement

Tags: perl

I am trying to make an script for a simple menu in a server using Perl, this menu has three options  ranging from 1 to 3 and if you input any other number it should prompt you to input a number fron 1 to 3. The code is as folows:

```
sub main_menu ()
{
        system('clear');
        print ('########## BIENVENIDOS A TERMINAL SERVER DE GOSIT ##########\n\n\n\n\n
            Seleccione una accion:\n\n
                1) Administracion de dispositivos\n
                2) Gestion de backups\n
                3) Salir del Terminal Server\n\n\n
        Ingrese opcion:   ');
        $action = <>;
        do
        {
                if ($action < '1' || $action > '3')
                {
                        print (" Por favor seleccione una opcion valida:    ");
                        $action = <>;
                        print ("\n\n");
                }
                elsif ($action == '1')
                {
                        #admin_menu();
                        print ("to admin menu\n");
                }
                elsif ($action == '2')
                {
                        #backup_menu();
                        print ("to backup menu\n");
                }
                elsif ($action == '3')
                {
                        print ("Saliendo de TERMINAL SERVER\n\n");
                        exit
                }
        } until ($action == '1' || $action == '2' ||$action == '3' );
}

main_menu();
```

While testing this script if the user inputs a number greater than 3 or lower than 1 the error message is prompted but if later any input value is enterd the script ends, here are the tests I made:

[image: Valid input 1]

[image: Valid input 2]

[image: Valid input 3]

[image: Invalid input 1]

[image: script misbehaviour]

Comment: 1) need to always remove the newline character from input, `chomp $action;`, after it's read from `<>`  2) Use numeric comparisons on numbers, not on strings: `if ($action == 1)` (not `'1'`)

Comment: Since the new input collection is inside the first if-clause, it will satisfy the loop option `unti ...` without re-checking the if-block. You should make it a while loop instead.

Comment: @zdim It is not always needed to remove the newline, but you should be aware that it is there, especially with `eq` comparisons to manual inputs.

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your loop control and print statements separate when you put the retry function inside the if-clause. Then execution will continue from the first if-clause, skip over all the other `elsif`s and skip right to the end, where it will satisfy the `until` and exit.

You also try to use `\n` inside a single quoted string. That will not work, you need a double quoted string.

What you need is to have just one read statement, and just retry the whole loop when the read fails. Like this

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub main_menu {
        while (1) {     # loop can only be exited manually
            system('clear');
            print '########## BIENVENIDOS A TERMINAL SERVER DE GOSIT ##########\n\n\n\n\n
            Seleccione una accion:\n\n
                1) Administracion de dispositivos\n
                2) Gestion de backups\n
                3) Salir del Terminal Server\n\n\n
        Ingrese opcion:   ';
            my $action = <>;
            no warnings 'numeric';    # disable numeric warnings

            if ($action == 1) {
                    print ("to admin menu\n");
            } elsif ($action == 2) {
                    print ("to backup menu\n");
            } elsif ($action == 3) {
                    print ("Saliendo de TERMINAL SERVER\n\n");
                    exit
            } else {
                    print (" Por favor seleccione una opcion valida.\n");
            }

            print "Press any key to continue...";    # needed to be able to read message
            <>;                                      # for pausing the screen
        };
}

main_menu();
```

Note the `no warnings 'numeric'` addition. This code relies on you running it with warnings off, or else you get warnings about numerical comparisons:

```
Argument "asd" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at ...
```

One way to fix it is to clean up the input and force it to be numerical, even when it is not. E.g.

```
$action =~ s/\D+//g;          # remove non-numbers
$action = 0 unless $action;   # if "" turn it into 0
```

Or you can just ignore those warnings

```
no warnings 'numeric';
```